# 16-bit CPU design: Issues with implementing fetch-execute cycle

Tags: verilog, cpu-registers, nand2tetris

I am doing a computer architecture course on Coursera called
NandtoTetris and have been struggling with my 16-bit CPU design. The
course uses a language called HDL, which is a very simple Verilog like
language.

I have spent so many hours trying to iterate on my CPU design based on
the diagram below and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I
tried my best to represent the fetch and execute mechanics. Does
anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Here are the design and control syntax diagram links:

CPU IO high-level diagram:
[image]

Gate level CPU diagram:
[image]

Control instruction syntax:
[image]

Here is my code below:

```
    // Put your code here:

    // Instruction decoding:from i of “ixxaccccccdddjjj” 
    // Ainstruction: Instruction is 16-bit value of the constant that should be loaded into the A register
    // C-instruction: The a- and c-bits code comp part, d- and j-bits code dest and jump(x-bits are ignored). 
    Mux16(a=outM, b=instruction, sel=instruction[15], out=aMUX); // 0 for A-instruction or 1 for a C-instruction  
    Not(in=instruction[15], out=aInst); // assert A instruction with op-code as true 
    And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[5], out=cInst); // assert wite-to-A-C-instruction with op code AND d1-bit
    Or(a=aInst, b=cInst, out=aMuxload); // assert Ainstruction or wite-to-A-C-instruction is true
    ARegister(in=aMUX, load=cInst, out=addressM); // load Ainstruction or wite-to-A-C-instruction 


    //  For C-instruction, a-bit determines if ALU will operate on A register input (0) vs M input (1)
    And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[12], out=Aselector); // assert that c instruction AND a-bit 
    Mux16(a=addressM, b=inM, sel=Aselector, out=aluMUX); // select A=0 or A=1           
    ALU(x=DregisterOut, y=aluMUX, zx=instruction[11], nx=instruction[10], zy=instruction[9], ny=instruction[8], f=instruction[7], no=instruction[6], zr=zr, ng=ng,out=outM); 

    // The 3 d-bits of “ixxaccccccdddjjj” ALUout determine registers are destinations for for ALUout
    // Whenever there is a C-Instruction and d2 (bit 4) is a 1 the D register is loaded
    And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[4], out=writeD); // assert that c instruction AND d2-bit
    DRegister(in=outM, load=writeD, out=DregisterOut); // d2 of d-bits for D register destination 

    // Whenever there is a C-Instruction and d3 (bit 3) is a 1 then writeM (aka RAM[A]) is true
    And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[3], out=writeM); // assert that c instruction AND d3-bit  

    // Programe counter to fetch next instruction
    // PC logic: if (reset==1), then PC = 0
    //           else:
    //                load  = comparison(instruction jump bits, ALU output zr & ng)
    //                if load == 1, PC = A
    //                else: PC ++   
    And(a=instruction[2], b=ng, out=JLT); // J2 test against ng: out < 0
    And(a=instruction[1], b=zr, out=JEQ); // J1 test against zr: out = 0
    Or(a=ng, b=zr, out=JGToutMnot)); // J0 test if ng and zr are both zero
    Not(in=JGToutMnot, out=JGToutM; // J0 test if ng and zr are both zero
    And(a=instruction[0], b=JGToutM, out=JGT);
    Or(a=JLT, b=JEQ, out=JLE); // out <= 0  
    Or(a=JGT, b=JLE, out=JMP); // final jump assertion
    And(a=instruction[15], b=JMP, out=PCload); // C instruction AND JMP assert to get the PC load bit
    // load in all values into the programme counter if load and reset, otherwise continue increasing
    PC(in=addressM, load=PCload, inc=true, reset=reset, out=pc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tricky to answer these kinds of questions without doing the work for you, which isn't helpful to you in the long run.

Some general thoughts.

- Consider each element in isolation (including the circles where signals come together).
- Label each line between elements with a name. These will become internal control lines. It helps reduce the chances of confusion.
- Be very careful about junk outputs. If you're not supposed to be putting valid data on outM, use a Mux to output false.

**Potential gotcha**: I seem to remember that it's a bad idea to use a design output (like outM) as an *input* to something else. Outputs should only be outputs. Right now you are sending the output of the ALU to outM and using outM as an input to other elements. I suggest you try outputting the ALU to a new signal "ALUout", and using that as the input for the other elements and (through a mux with false controlled by writeM) outM. But remember, writeM is an output! So the block that generates writeM needs to generate a *copy* of itself to use as the control to the mux. FORTUNATELY, a block can have multiple out statements!

For example, right now you're generating outM like this (I won't comment on whether it is wrong, I am just using it as an illustration):

```
And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[3], out=writeM);
```

You can create a second output like this:

```
And(a=instruction[15], b=instruction[3], out=writeM, out=writeM2)
```

and then "clean" your outM like this:

```
Mux16(a=false,b=ALUout,sel=writeM2,out=outM);
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much. I should have specified the input, output API for the CPU design and that would have made it easier for you to understand all the outputs in the chips. It turns out that the biggest issue was that the A register final output was supposed to be 15 bits instead of 16, while the A register output that feeds into the 2nd Mux was correct at 16 bits. Mismatch of bus sizes for the A register outputs basically, and same for the Programme Counter (PC) :).